# How best to annotate the purpose of a branch in SVN

Tags: svn, branch

We have several branches of the same project in a repository to be used for different project purposes. We work different ones at different times and not everyone knows which branches are for which purpose. What is a good way to associate an easy-to-find note of some kind with each branch that would simply describe in a sentence or two what the branch is for? Are Properties a good way to do this, and if so, which property?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to annotate the purpose of a branch in SVN is "Do not annotate at all, but give every branch meaningful name"

**If** your team will follow "branch-per-task" workflow **and** will have good ticket-system (with SVN-inegration) you'll avoid a lot of headaches: just imagine pair

- ticket "#177 Fix Broken calc.c"
- branch Ticket-177

From other side, you can use any (strictly policy-driven) [property of commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html), defined in (strictly policy-driven, but I'll suggest first commit /creating/ of branch) any commit of branch (first commit just for easier searchability later) - read about `--with-revprop` commit option

***Addition***

If you, for some|any reason don't want to use revision-properties, but still want to have some type of annotation for custom path, you can use SVN file|folder [properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.manip), something like (TBT!)

```
svn propset description 'Branch for some task' branches/branch1
svn propset description 'Branch for another task' branches/branch2
```

…
(from the root of repo, with default tree) for setting property and

```
svn propget description branches/branch1
```

for getting it later

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I created 5 branches for 5 aspects of a project named like "<ticket> <standard 3-word project name> <to-brief-an-identifier-I-guess-#1>," "<...#2>...," etc. While working on one or two, forgot what the others were strictly for. I can keep a note somewhere what the branches are for but I like to keep that info with the branch. Then, if someone asks, I can refer them there or remind myself. I also didn't want to be more verbose with the names. New to SVN, I was surprised there was no description property on the branch for a note about which task each branch is for.

Comment: @RPrgrmr - no, just **add** *any* property to folder|file, if you want it. I'll extend answer with 2-nd solution noe